# android: move to touch location after release with libgdx/universal-tween-engine

Tags: android, libgdx, tween

I'm learning to use libgdx with universal-tween-engine and haven't been able to figure out how to touch (or click on the desktop app) a point on the screen and have a texture move all the way to the touched location without keeping the touch or click active until the end-point is reached.

When the touch event is initiated, the animation begins and the graphic moves towards the location. The graphic will follow the finger/mouse-pointer if a touch and drag is initiated. If I touch a point, the graphic will move towards the point until the touch is released. Then it stops where it was when touch is released.

I'm looking to touch-and-release and have that graphic move to the touched point, and am probably not understanding something about the tween engine implementation. I've pasted the tweening code below.

```
    public void render() {

            camera.update();

            batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(texture.getTexture(), texture.getBoundingBox().x, texture.getBoundingBox().y);
            batch.end();

            Tween.registerAccessor(Plane.class, new TextureAccessor());
            TweenManager planeManager = new TweenManager();

            float newX = 0;
            float newY = 0;
            boolean animateOn = false;

            if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
                    newX = Gdx.input.getX();

                    newY = Gdx.input.getY();

                    animateOn = true;
            }

            if (animateOn == true && (texture.getX() != newX || texture.getY() != newY)) {
                Tween.to(texture, TextureAccessor.POSITION_XY, 10)
                    .target(newX, newY)
                    .ease(TweenEquations.easeNone)
                    .start(planeManager);

                    planeManager.update(1);

                    if (texture.getX() == newX && texture.getY() == newY) {
                        animateOn = false;
                    }
            }

    }
```

Originally, I had the tweening code inside the conditional for [`isTouched()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/RemoteInput.html#isTouched%28%29) and didn't use the `newX`, `newY` or `animateOn` variables. I thought using `isTouched()` to only set the new coordinates and animation state would then make the loop trigger the tween. The older code looked like this:

```
    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            newX = Gdx.input.getX();

            newY = Gdx.input.getY();

            Tween.to(texture, TextureAccessor.POSITION_XY, 10)
                .target(newX, newY)
                .ease(TweenEquations.easeNone)
                .start(planeManager);

            planeManager.update(1);
    }
```

I've also tried using [`justTouched()`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/RemoteInput.html#justTouched%28%29), but the graphic would only move very slightly toward the touched point.

I've been struggling with this for a few hours, I'd really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Tween.registerAccessor(Plane.class, new TextureAccessor());
TweenManager planeManager = new TweenManager();
```

These two lines should go in the `create()` method, not the `render()` one! Here, you're instantiating a new manager on every frame, you only need one manager, that's all, not an army of them!

Also, you need to update the manager on every frame, not just when `animateOn` is true, else you'll need to keep your finger pressed...

The correct code is as follows, learn from it, you'll get a better understanding of how the Tween Engine works :)

```
// Only one manager is needed, like a Spritebatch
private TweenManager planeManager;

public void create() {
    Tween.registerAccessor(Plane.class, new TextureAccessor());
    planeManager = new TweenManager();
}

public void render() {
    // The manager needs to be updated on every frame.
    planeManager.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    camera.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture.getTexture(), texture.getBoundingBox().x, texture.getBoundingBox().y);
    batch.end();

    // When the user touches the screen, we start an animation.
    // The animation is managed by the TweenManager, so there is
    // no need to use an "animateOn" boolean.
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        // Bonus: if there is already an animation running,
        // we kill it to prevent conflicts with the new animation.
        planeManager.killTarget(texture);

        // Fire the animation! :D
        Tween.to(texture, TextureAccessor.POSITION_XY, 10)
            .target(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())
            .ease(TweenEquations.easeNone)
            .start(planeManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and correct answer. I'd run into memory issues when testing on my phone, and got rid of the multiple tween managers all over the place. That animateOn is for the beginning of a turn based module, I probably should have left it out of the question. Thanks for the help and the great library.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to implement this behavior in the wrong way. Instead of using `isTouched` or `justTouched()`, I needed to use `touchDown()` from [`GestureListener`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.GestureListener.html).

I created a class that implemented GestureDetector (call it `touchListener()`)inside of my main class (the one that implements ApplicationLisetener )in the main libgdx project and put the x and y capturing code inside of `toucDown` (I noticed `tap()` was also being triggered). I moved the tween functions  (the actual tweening, the call to `registerAccessor()`, and the creation of the new tween manager) into the `update()` method of `touchListener()`.

I added a call to `touchListener()`'s update function inside the `render()` loop of the main libgdx class.

I doubt I did this is the best way, but I hope it's helpful to someone else in the future.

Comment: It's not the best way, and actually it works because you are lucky :) You really shouldn't create a new tween manager in a touch listener. A manager is only required once in a project. It's like a Spritebatch, or a Camera. You only create one instance of them :) Have a look at my answer for the correct solution, it will guide you in using the tween engine.